# Magento custom module Observer not working

Tags: php, magento

I have created my custom module in magento at app/code/local/mycustom/GeoLocation, in that i want to create a observer so i had followed lot of tutorials and at last i had created below code to call it on every page load of magento but still it is not calling my observer.php of custom module.I am new to magento so please help me.

**config.xml**

```
<config>
    <global>
        <events>
            <cms_page_render>
                <observers>
                    <mycustom_GeoLocation_Model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>mycustom_GeoLocation_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>getGeoLocation</method>
                    </mycustom_GeoLocation_Model_observer>
                </observers>
            </cms_page_render>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

**mycustomGeolocation_Event.xml for enabling module**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <mycustom_GeoLocation>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
        </mycustom_GeoLocation>
    </modules> 
</config>
```

**At last my observer.php which is present in model of my custom module**

```
class mycustom_GeoLocation_Model_Observer {

   public function __construct()
   {
   }

    public function getGeoLocation(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {   // current layout

         $event = $observer->getEvent();
         $cms_page = $event->getPage();  
         echo "called";
         exit;
         return $this;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of issue in modules.

As observer `die() may be not works`.Use Magento `log print to check the  observer work or not`

Module NameSpace Folder name should be start with `upper letter mycustom to Mycustom`. Also You need change class name respesctive code.

### Update:

**config.xml code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mycustom_GeoLocation>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mycustom_GeoLocation>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <geolocation>
        <class>Mycustom_GeoLocation_Model</class>
      </geolocation>
    </models>
    <events>
      <cms_page_render> 
        <observers>
          <cms_page_render_handler> 
            <type>model</type> 
            <class>geolocation/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>getGeoLocation</method>  
           </cms_page_render_handler>
        </observers>
      </cms_page_render>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

You can get full module at [github](https://github.com/devamitbera/magento-stackexchange/tree/master/stack)

Comment: thanks amit for your reply can you please elaborate it because i am new to it.

Comment: wait a minute i just check it and tell you

Comment: i don't know who had down voted i need 125 reputation to down vote

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80171/discussion-between-rupesh-deotale-and-amit-bera).